# Gmail Android Rendering? Ignoring all CSS from Style head tag 2021

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I have create an email template. Looks good in Hotmail. But recently start looking bad in Gmail.

Ignoring all the CSS from the  section inside the  tag.

Looks my testing process using Mailchimp: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/2973759?key=83e5d9f231a7ecaa7af64a28bf390b97

The Gmail Android app is ignoring all the CSS and media queries. And is very strange because some days ago the template looked good. Gmail app was updated?

Please, someone could help me?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine  -->
    <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
    <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
    <!-- Please use an inliner tool to convert all CSS to inline as inpage or external CSS is removed by email clients -->
    <!-- important in CSS is used to prevent the styles of currently inline CSS from overriding the ones mentioned in media queries when corresponding screen sizes are encountered -->
    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
      html,body{
      background:#ffffff;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      margin:0 !important;
      padding:0 !important;
      width:100% !important;
      }
      *{
      -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
      }
      .ExternalClass{
      width:100%;
      }
      div[style*=margin: 16px 0]{
      margin:0 !important;
      }
      table,td{
      mso-table-lspace:0 !important;
      mso-table-rspace:0 !important;
      }
      table{
      border-spacing:0 !important;
      border-collapse:separate !important;
      table-layout:fixed !important;
      margin:0 auto !important;
      }
      table table table{
      table-layout:auto;
      }
      img{
      -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
      }
      .yshortcuts a{
      border-bottom:none !important;
      }
      a[x-apple-data-detectors]{
      color:inherit !important;
      }
      .mcnPreviewText{
      display:none !important;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
      .email-container{
      width:100% !important;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .padding_0_top{
      padding-top:0 !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .padding_0{
      padding-right:0 !important;
      padding-left:0 !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .padding_10{
      padding-right:10px !important;
      padding-left:10px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .padding_10_left{
      padding-left:15px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .padding_10_right{
      padding-right:15px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .padding_30{
      padding-right:30px !important;
      padding-left:30px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .font_m{
      font-size:30px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .font_ms{
      font-size:24px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .font_s{
      font-size:20px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .font_xs{
      font-size:16px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .font_xxs{
      font-size:14px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .font_mini{
      font-size:12px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .hide{
      display:none !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .button{
      padding:10px 25px !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .centermobile{
      text-align:center !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .blockmobile{
      display:block !important;
      }
      } @media screen and (max-width:480px){
      .marginmobile{
      margin:0 auto !important;
      }
      } /*
      @tab Page
      @section heading 1
      @tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails. These should be the largest of your headings.
      @style heading 1
      */
      h1{
      /*@editable*/color:#2A2A33;
      display:block;
      /*@editable*/font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana,sans-serif;
      /*@editable*/font-size:16px;
      /*@editable*/font-style:normal;
      /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
      /*@editable*/line-height:22px;
      /*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
      margin-top:0;
      margin-right:0;
      margin-bottom:15px;
      margin-left:0;
      }
      /*
      @tab Page
      @section heading 2
      @tip Set the styling for all second-level headings in your emails.
      @style heading 2
      */
      h2{
      /*@editable*/color:#2A2A33;
      display:block;
      /*@editable*/font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana,sans-serif;
      /*@editable*/font-size:22px;
      /*@editable*/font-style:normal;
      /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
      /*@editable*/line-height:26px;
      /*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
      margin-top:0;
      margin-right:0;
      margin-bottom:15px;
      margin-left:0;
      }
      /*
      @tab Page
      @section heading 3
      @tip Set the styling for all third-level headings in your emails.
      @style heading 3
      */
      h3{
      /*@editable*/color:#2A2A33;
      display:block;
      /*@editable*/font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana,sans-serif;
      /*@editable*/font-size:20px;
      /*@editable*/font-style:normal;
      /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
      /*@editable*/line-height:120%;
      /*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
      margin-top:10px;
      margin-right:0;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      margin-left:0;
      }
      /*
      @tab Page
      @section heading 4
      @tip Set the styling for all fourth-level headings in your emails. These should be the smallest of your headings.
      @style heading 4
      */
      h4{
      /*@editable*/color:#2A2A33;
      display:block;
      /*@editable*/font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana,sans-serif;
      /*@editable*/font-size:16px;
      /*@editable*/font-style:italic;
      /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
      /*@editable*/line-height:120%;
      /*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
      margin-top:0;
      margin-right:0;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      margin-left:0;
      }
      /*
      @tab Header
      @section header text
      @tip Set the styling for your email's header text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
      */
      .headerContent{
      /*@editable*/color:#2A2A33;
      /*@editable*/font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana,sans-serif;
      /*@editable*/font-size:24px;
      /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
      /*@editable*/line-height:120%;
      /*@editable*/text-align:center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:separate;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <center style="width:100%;">
         
          
                  <!-- Bullets: BEGIN -->
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container" style="border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;border-style: none solid none solid;border-color: #BDBDBD;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" mc:repeatable="content_block" mc:variant="body_bullets">
                    <tr>
                      <td mc:edit="bullets_tittle">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="padding_0_top" align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:15px 30px 10px;" >
                              <div class="font_xxs" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana;font-size:17px;font-weight:normal;line-height:33px;text-align:justify;color:#000000;">
                                <b>What you will find in the map?</b>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
                        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:180px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:20%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="width:31px;vertical-align:middle;" mc:edit="bullet_icon_1">
                                              <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/f06a7adde287b86cfdbb649dc/images/6396e6cf-e330-443c-bcf5-07402afdfe1e.png" style="border: 0;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto;width: 100%;font-size: 13px;max-width: 31px;border-radius: 0px;line-height: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="31" alt="bffb611b-4baf-410c-9964-6e5a2e6ee59d.png">
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:420px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:80%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;" mc:edit="bullets_text_1">
                                      <div class="padding_10 font_xxs centermobile" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana;font-size:17px;font-weight:500;line-height:23px;text-align:justify;color:#000000;padding:0px 5px 0px;">
                                        Information about relevant properties for you.
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
                        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:120px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:20%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="width:40px;vertical-align:middle;" mc:edit="bullet_icon_2">
                                              <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/f06a7adde287b86cfdbb649dc/images/af475449-755a-4abb-b1ab-fb36cc75f4ac.png" style="border: 0;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto;width: 100%;font-size: 13px;max-width: 40px;border-radius: 0px;line-height: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="40" alt="bffb611b-4baf-410c-9964-6e5a2e6ee59d.png">
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:480px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:80%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;" mc:edit="bullets_text_2">
                                      <div class="padding_10 font_xxs centermobile" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana;font-size:17px;font-weight:500;line-height:23px;text-align:justify;color:#000000;padding:0px 5px 0px;">
                                        Information about the relevant neighborhoods
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
                        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:120px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:20%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="width:25px;vertical-align:middle;" mc:edit="bullet_icon_3">
                                              <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/f06a7adde287b86cfdbb649dc/images/cee2d429-1d6d-4835-9989-6e518a3e49ad.png" style="border: 0;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto;width: 100%;font-size: 13px;max-width: 25px;border-radius: 0px;line-height: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="25" alt="bffb611b-4baf-410c-9964-6e5a2e6ee59d.png">
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:480px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:80%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px" mc:edit="bullets_text_3">
                                      <div class="padding_10 font_xxs centermobile" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana;font-size:17px;font-weight:500;line-height:23px;text-align:justify;color:#000000;padding:0px 5px 0px;">
                                        Information about the surrounding areas
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
                        <!--[if mso | IE]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:120px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:20%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="dominant-baseline: ">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="width:25px;vertical-align:middle;" mc:edit="bullet_icon_4">
                                              <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/f06a7adde287b86cfdbb649dc/images/7d405a03-282e-45b5-93e3-ded47ac28b95.png" style="border: 0;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto;width: 100%;font-size: 13px;max-width: 25px;border-radius: 0px;line-height: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="25" alt="bffb611b-4baf-410c-9964-6e5a2e6ee59d.png">
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;width:480px;">
                              <![endif]-->
                              <div class="blockmobile marginmobile" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;max-width:80%;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;" mc:edit="bullets_text_4">
                                      <div class="padding_10 font_xxs centermobile" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana;font-size:17px;font-weight:500;line-height:23px;text-align:justify;color:#000000;padding:0px 5px 0px;">
                                        Information about transportation
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if mso | IE]>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!-- Bullets : END -->
                  
                  <!-- Divisor gris 70px : BEGIN -->
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container" style="border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;border-style: none solid none solid;border-color: #BDBDBD;border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"mc:repeatable="content_block" mc:variant="single_line_divider_70">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="padding:35px 25px;">
                                <tr>
                                  <td height="1px" style="text-align:center;mso-height-rule:exactly;font-size:1px;margin:0px auto;width:100%;display:block;max-height: 1px;">
                                    <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/f06a7adde287b86cfdbb649dc/images/82977c1d-25c4-4c62-8f26-69776b2d70f7.png" style="border: 0;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto;font-size: 13px;line-height: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;margin: 0 auto;max-width: 550px;max-height: 1px;background-color:#BDBDBD;background:#BDBDBD; " width="100%" >
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!-- Divisor gris 70px: END -->
                
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END -->
            <!-- Email footer : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container" style="border-width:0px 1px 1px 1px;border-style:none solid solid solid;border-color:#BDBDBD;border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;">
              <tr>
                <td dir="ltr" align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding:0px 15px 15px;">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td mc:edit="footer_description">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                         
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td mc:edit="unsub_link">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px 51px;" >
                              <a href="*|UNSUB|*" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:'Open Sans', Verdana;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:160%;text-align:center;color:#2081DA;"> Unsubscribe from this email </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Email footer : END -->
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found an error in your HTML at line 463 - 465. Your outer/wrapper table is being closed off just before `<!-- Email Body : END -->`. See if fixing that fixes your Gmail. Gmail is very particular on proper code being sent

Answer (score 0):

Gmail’s CSS parser is very sensitive. And if it sees something it doesn't like, it will usually remove the entirety of the `<style>` tag containing the faulty style. In your case, it comes to the following rule:

```css
div[style*=margin: 16px 0]{
      margin:0 !important;
}
```

Adding quote around the value in the attribute selector fixes it and is enough to tame Gmail.

```css
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"]{
      margin:0 !important;
}
```

A good way to solve this kind of problem is to split your styles into lots of `<style>` tags. This way, Gmail will only remove the `<style>` tag containing the faulty rule, so you can see which styles are kept and which one are not. And because Gmail’s CSS parser is usually the same between mobile and desktop, you can even debug this in Gmail’s desktop webmail, using your browser’s dev tools to inspect the code directly.